# Select a class from dublicate classes using JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-scraping, cheerio

So I have been a mess for days. I am scraping a website for particular information. The problem is that the website has two css classes but with an identical name. I want to use the link and text from the first css class. Attached is the image of what I have. I want to only use the href values from 1 and not the ones from the two "regions".
[image]

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require("axios");

const siteUrl = "https://worldpostalcode.com/nigeria/abia/";
const fetchData = async () => {
  const result = await axios.get(siteUrl);
  return cheerio.load(result.data);
};

const getData = async (html) => {
  const stateList = []

  const $ = await fetchData();
  const stateUrl = $('.regions',html);
  //console.log(stateUrl.length)
  console.log(stateUrl.length)
 
  for (let index = 0; index < 1; index++) {
    let firstRegion = $(stateUrl[index],'a')
    stateList.push(firstRegion)
  }
  console.log(stateList)
}
getData()
```

Help please

Comment: You can use something like this: https://pastebin.com/0J0apkMS

Comment: When you do `const stateUrl = $('.regions',html);`, you get a collection of `.regions`.  If you just want the first one, just dip into the collection and get the first one by indexing it with `[0]`.

Comment: @ChrisG, thanks a lot. You deserve a bottle of beer. I was almost running mad. Now i see what i was missing. 
Can you move that solution to the answer section so others can easily benefit?

Comment: You're welcome but I'm not going to post an answer; all of that can be gleaned from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the previous h2 text:

```
$('h2:contains(Regions) + div.regions a')
```